# How to get mouse cursor not to move while dragging inside a custom NSView?

Tags: cocoa, mouse, drag, nsview, nsevent

I have a custom NSView and I want the user to be able to click and drag inside it. NSView of course will receive the mouse drag events and respond appropriately. While the mouse is being dragged I want to make sure that the mouse cursor doesn't move.

I could probably hide the cursor and make it reappear at the same location once the user stops dragging but is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Seems like it would be very counter-intuitive.

Comment: NSView I am talking about is the main NSWindows' NSView. The drag function is not actually dragging a slider or anything like that, it becomes a gesture that affects the state of the application. The dragging a mouse anywhere around the application performs a single function. The way I'm trying to design the app should make it obvious to the user what the mouse drag does. But that's another problem.

Answer (score 2):

Nicer solution – use the `CGAssociateMouseAndMouseCursorPosition` function to enable/disable the cursor from moving.

Your way of just jumping the mouse back can sometimes appear to the user as the mouse moving a little bit, and then jumping back really quickly.

Comment: This currently doesn't work with SwiftUI drag gestures. Translation values are not updated as long as the mouse is disconnected from the cursor.

Answer (score 1):

Ended up observing kCGEventLeftMouseDragged events and then calling CGWarpMouseCursorPosition to reset the mouse position. The cursor stays put the whole time I'm dragging.